# Как обернуть одни теги исключая другие без множества?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно обернуть все теги в блоке `.article-section-post`, исключая некоторые. При использовании `.wrapAll()` результатом будет один отдельный блок.
`.wrap()` в свою очередь берет каждый тег в нужный мне блок. При построении страницы, это влияет на отображение ширины контента. Еще бы, столько обёрток.

[Пример (сайт).](http://predaytor.com/t/jekyll/jekyll-begin/)

Вопрос: как пройтись по всем элементам родителя `.article-section-post` открывая тег `<div class="max-width-740">`, и закрывая при случае, к примеру `ul, ol, pre, blockquote`. После конструкция повторяется.

```
$(".article-section-post > *").not("pre, ol, ul, blockquote").wrap("<div class='width-740' />");
```

Пропущенные элементы врапаю так:

```
$(".article-section-post").find("ul, ol, blockquote").wrap("<div class='width-740-non-padding' />");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 let $articleElements = $(".article-section-post").children();
      let $parts = [];
      let indx = 0;

      while (true) {
        if ($($articleElements[indx]).is("pre, ol, ul, blockquote")) {
          $($parts).wrapAll('<div class="width-740"/>');
          $articleElements = $articleElements.slice(++indx);
          $parts = [];
          indx = 0;
          continue;
        }
        $parts.push($articleElements[indx]);
        indx++;
        if (indx > $articleElements.length - 1) break;
      }
      $($parts).wrapAll('<div class="width-740"/>');
```

Comment: Все так же, каждый дочерний тег попадает в новый `.width-740.` При построении страницы класс добавляется когда DOM уже готов, причем так много, каждому элементу кроме выборки `.not()`;

Comment: На сайте который вы показали уже есть скрипт который добаляет классы width-740 и width-740-non-padding в файле http://predaytor.com/assets/js/preload.js
Вот так будет выглядеть дом с моим скриптом без того что написано в preload.js http://prntscr.com/mh3da8 Вы же этого добиваетесь, или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: Правильно, я пробывал подключить отдельные строки jquery кода линком `preload`. Но не получилось. Ваш код делает тоже самое, просто вместо `*` вы указали `children()`. Мне нужно что бы все теги обернулись в один `.width-740`, пока js не наткнется на выборку `.not()`. Он пропускает к примеру тег '<pre>` после чего вновь открывает `.width-740`. Мне нужно убрать множество оберток каждого тега, ведь их можно засунуть в один блок, это призывает к медленному построению стилей элементов.

Comment: А пропущенную выборку и нужно врапать в `.non-width-740`, они одиночки. После идут абзацы и так далее.

Comment: Еще раз. Вы добиваетесь того, что бы каждый ПЕРВЫЙ дочерний элемент блока с классом .article-section-post был с классом .max-width-740 или вы хотите что бы все элементы были обернуты в один блок, но в этой обертке не должно быть элементов "ul, ol, pre, blockquote" вот так наверное?

Comment: Где я неясно выражаюсь? Нет, не каждый первый, а каждая группа без элементов `not()`. Если обернуть все элементы без `.not()` это равносильно `.wrapAll`. Это сломает все. К примеру, открываем тег `.width-740`, далее идут подряд `h1, p`.., и если вдруг попадается что-то из выбоки NOT - закрываем тег перед ним, после пропускаем его и открываем `.width-740` вновь, и так далее.

Comment: Отредактировал код, попробуйте

Comment: Большое спасибо.